# Continuity of matrix trace functionals

Tags: matrices, continuity, matrix-calculus, quantum-information

Let $P$ be a positive $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, let $f:(0,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and define a function on positive definite $n\times n$ matrices as
$$
Q\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(P f(Q)).\tag{$\ast$}
$$
This is well defined for positive *definite* matrices $Q$, but it can be extended to positive *semi*-definite matrices $Q$ as long as $\mathrm{null}(Q)\subseteq\mathrm{null}(P)$. We can write this extension in terms of the eigenvalues of $Q$ and $P$ as 
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(Pf(Q)) = \sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^n p_j f(q_i) \lvert \langle u_i,v_j\rangle\rvert^2
$$
where the spectral decompositions of $P$ and $Q$ are
$$
P = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i v_iv_i^* 
\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
Q = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i u_iu_i^*
$$
 with $q_1,\dots,q_r>0$ and $q_{r+1}=\cdots=q_{n}=0$.

For example, the [quantum relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_relative_entropy) of two positive $n\times n$ matrices $P,Q\in\mathrm{H}_n^+$ can be defined as
$$
D(P\lVert Q) = \mathrm{Tr}(P\log P) - \mathrm{Tr}(P\log Q)
$$
whenever $\mathrm{null}(Q)\subseteq\mathrm{null}(P)$ and as $D(P\lVert Q)=+\infty$ otherwise.

It seems that the relative entropy is continuous (when it is extended to $Q$ such that $\mathrm{null}\subseteq\mathrm{null}(P)$). My question is:

1. How do we know that $Q\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(P\log(Q))$ is continuous?
2. For a fixed $P$, for which other functions $f$ can the function in ($\ast$) be continuously extended to $Q$ satisfying $\mathrm{null}(Q)\subseteq\mathrm{null}(P)$?
3. If $f$ can be continuously extended to $0$, then this function is obviously continuous. What about $f(x)=x^r$ for some $r\leq0$? It seems that $Q\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(PQ^r)$ is continuous for $r\geq-1$, but I'd like to have a proof if it!

See an example of such functions [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1335.pdf).

Comment: Without having thought about this excessively, at least for 1. (and maybe even 3?) it might be useful to subdivide the map in question into $Q\mapsto \log(Q)$ (respectively $Q\mapsto Q^r$) and $X\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(PX)$ - as the latter is a linear functional on a finite-dimensional space, hence bounded - so that only leaves you with the first map.

Comment: I want to extend continuity to matrices that are not positive definite. The problem is that $\log(Q)$ isn't even *defined* if $Q$ is not positive definite. However, the value of $\mathrm{Tr}(P\log(Q))$ is well defined if $\mathrm{null}(Q)\subset\mathrm{null}(P)$, and $Q\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(P\log(Q))$ is continuous where it is defined. The same problem pops up with $Q\mapsto Q^r$ when $r<0$. It could be that $Q\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(PQ^r)$ is continuous at a non positive definite $Q$ even though $Q^r$ isn't even defined.

Comment: I'd like to be able to show that $Q\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(PQ^r)$ is continuous at a singular positive semidefinite $Q$ in the sense that the limit $\lim_{R\rightarrow Q}\mathrm{Tr}(PR^r)$ exists, where the limit is taken over all positive definite matrices.